# Seg fault while reading files after choosing CL platform

Tags: c, file-io, opencl

I'm new to OpenCL. I'm trying to read from files and do some computations with that data in OpenCL. However, when I add the code to choose platforms in, the read function doesn't work anymore. It was working before.

Just a little more information: The input file format is just a list of floats with one number per line.
Here's the piece of code that I added in:

```c
cl_uint numPlatforms;

  int err;
  err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
  if (err != CL_SUCCESS || numPlatforms <= 0)
    {
      printf("Error: Failed to find a platform!\n%s\n",err_code(err));
      return EXIT_FAILUR;
    }
```

The whole file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <CL/cl.h>

#include <sys/time.h>


#define STR_SIZE 256

void fatal(char *s)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", s);
}

void read(float *vec, int numRows, int numCols, int layers, char *file)
{
  int i, j, k;
  FILE *fp;
  char str[STR_SIZE];
  float val;
  if((fp = fopen(file,"r"))==0) printf("Could not open file to read\n");
  for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
      for(k = 0; k < layers; k++)
        {
          fgets(str, STR_SIZE, fp);
          if(feof(fp)) fatal("not enough lines\n");
          if(sscanf(str, "%f", &val) != 1) fatal("invalid file format\n");
          vec[i*numCols + j + k * numRows * numCols] = val;     
        }
  fclose(fp);
}

void write(float *vec, int numRows, int numCols, int layers, char *file)
{
  int i, j, k, index = 0;
  FILE *fp;
  char str[STR_SIZE];
  if((fp = fopen(file,"w"))==0) printf("Could not open file to write\n");
  for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
      for (k = 0; k < layers; k++)
        {
          sprintf(str, "%d\t%g\n", index, vec[i*numCols+j + numRows * numCols * k]);
          fputs(str,fp);
          index++;  
        }   
  fclose(fp);   
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  char *pfile, *tfile, *ofile;

  pfile = argv[3];
  tfile = argv[4];
  ofile = argv[5];

  int numCols = atoi(argv[1]);
  int numRows = atoi(argv[1]);
  int layers = atoi(argv[2]);


  float *powerIn, *tempOut, *tempIn, *tempCopy;

  int size = numCols * numRows * layers;

  powerIn = (float*)calloc(size, sizeof(float));
  tempIn = (float*)calloc(size,sizeof(float));
  tempOut = (float*)calloc(size, sizeof(float));
  float* answer = (float*)calloc(size, sizeof(float));

  read(powerIn,numRows, numCols, layers, pfile);
  read(tempIn, numRows, numCols, layers, tfile);

  size_t global;                   

  cl_device_id     device_id;     
  cl_context       context;       
  cl_command_queue commands;     
  cl_program       program;       
  cl_kernel        ko_vadd;             
memcpy(tempCopy,tempIn, size * sizeof(float));
  cl_mem d_a;                     // device memory used for the input  a vector
  cl_mem d_b;                     // device memory used for the input  b vector
  cl_mem d_c;                     // device memory used for the output c vector
  //This piece of code causes the problem. Without it, the program works fine.
  cl_uint numPlatforms;


  int err;
  err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
  if (err != CL_SUCCESS || numPlatforms <= 0)
    {
      printf("Error: Failed to find a platform!\n%s\n",err_code(err));
      return EXIT_FAILUR;
    }

  write(tempIn,numRows, numCols, layers, ofile);
  free(tempIn);
  free(tempOut); 
  free(powerIn);
  return 0;
}
```

err_code.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>

char *err_code (cl_int err_in)
{
    switch (err_in) {

        case CL_SUCCESS :
            return (char*)" CL_SUCCESS ";
        case CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND :
            return (char*)" CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND ";
        case CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE :
            return (char*)" CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE ";
        case CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE :
            return (char*)" CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE ";
        case CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE :
            return (char*)" CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE ";
        case CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES :
            return (char*)" CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES ";
        case CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY :
            return (char*)" CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY ";
        case CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE :
            return (char*)" CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE ";
        case CL_MEM_COPY_OVERLAP :
            return (char*)" CL_MEM_COPY_OVERLAP ";
        case CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_MISMATCH :
            return (char*)" CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_MISMATCH ";
        case CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED :
            return (char*)" CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED ";
        case CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE :
            return (char*)" CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE ";
        case CL_MAP_FAILURE :
            return (char*)" CL_MAP_FAILURE ";
        case CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET :
            return (char*)" CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET ";
        case CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST :
            return (char*)" CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST ";
        case CL_INVALID_VALUE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_VALUE ";
        case CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE ";
        case CL_INVALID_PLATFORM :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_PLATFORM ";
        case CL_INVALID_DEVICE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_DEVICE ";
        case CL_INVALID_CONTEXT :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_CONTEXT ";
        case CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES ";
        case CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE ";
        case CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR ";
        case CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT ";
        case CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR ";
        case CL_INVALID_IMAGE_SIZE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_IMAGE_SIZE ";
        case CL_INVALID_SAMPLER :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_SAMPLER ";
        case CL_INVALID_BINARY :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_BINARY ";
        case CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS ";
        case CL_INVALID_PROGRAM :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_PROGRAM ";
        case CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE ";
        case CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME ";
        case CL_INVALID_KERNEL_DEFINITION :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_KERNEL_DEFINITION ";
        case CL_INVALID_KERNEL :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_KERNEL ";
        case CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX ";
        case CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE ";
        case CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE ";
        case CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS ";
        case CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION ";
        case CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE ";
        case CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE ";
        case CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET ";
        case CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST ";
        case CL_INVALID_EVENT :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_EVENT ";
        case CL_INVALID_OPERATION :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_OPERATION ";
        case CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT ";
        case CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE ";
        case CL_INVALID_MIP_LEVEL :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_MIP_LEVEL ";
        case CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE ";
        case CL_INVALID_PROPERTY :
            return (char*)" CL_INVALID_PROPERTY ";
        default:
            return (char*)"UNKNOWN ERROR";

    }
}
```

Makefile:

```c
ifndef CC
    CC = gcc
endif

CCFLAGS=-O3 -lm -g

LIBS = -lOpenCL -fopenmp

3D: 3D.c err_code.c 
    $(CC) $^ $(CCFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@


clean:
    rm -f 3D
```

Comment: `read` and `write` are system calls on Unix-type operating systems like Linux. Try renaming the functions to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some my observation  says these are possible issues.

```
memcpy(tempCopy,tempIn, size * sizeof(float));
```

here memory for `tempCopy` not allocated. You need to allocate first memory for it.

In `read` function there are lines

```
if((fp = fopen(file,"r"))==0) printf("Could not open file to read\n");
```

Here if file open failed then still you are going to read file. Need `return` statement when `fopen` failed.And note break/return when any operation failed.No go for further processing. You can look many condition checking in your code and you just display message for this if it's failed not take any action ( `break/return`) and going to further processing.First correct this one.

Also in for loop you have following lines

```
     fgets(str, STR_SIZE, fp);
      if(feof(fp)) fatal("not enough lines\n");
```

here you first read file then check if it empty or not.This is wrong way. You first check if file is empty or not. if empty then break loop else read it. like

```
    if(!feof(fp))
    {
      fgets(str, STR_SIZE, fp);
    }
    else
    {
       fatal("not enough lines\n");
       break;
    }
```

Also `read` and `write` are unix system calls.this will cause conflication.So batter you change name for your user defined functions.